# Duplicated Windows 2008 domain server

Tags: active-directory

Here is our problem. We got a Windows 2008 Enterprise Server acting as active directory domain server. This AD is installed on a server "SERVER_A".

We've got a server "SERVER_B" which has identical configuration both in hardware and software but AD capabilities.

We're defining a backup and restoration process, since in case of catastrophic event, we don't want to loose AD information sited in "SERVER_A" (I'm thinking on Hard Disk crash) or, eventually restore it quickly.

We're wondering whether is any way to have a "Duplicated" domain server in server "SERVER_B" to support AD functionality in case "SERVER_A" was lost, something like a "Domain Server Farm" which were synchronized.

The other option we're considering is performing a regular backup on an external USB hard disk of Active Directory (like snapshot does) sited on "SERVER_A" to perform a restoration on "SERVER_B".

I'm sure there must be a way to solve this problem, but we have recently moved from UNIX technologies to Windows 2008 and we still being a little stuck with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is exactly how every Active Directory installation should be performed. You should never have less than two domain controllers on your network.

You can use `dcpromo` to configure a Windows 2008 server as a domain controller.

This [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733027(v=ws.10).aspx) article explains how to do this.

Comment: We're going to follow the technet article, and i will let you know shortly

Comment: That was simple and great.